# python requests sending files in array shows ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-requests

What is the problem Here ?

I got an error shows

**ValueError: too many values to unpack**

This code process is to get all available images in a folder then put that images location into an array. Then create an other array called files and add image location with specific format and send the POST request to the API

```py
import requests
import logging
import os
import json

try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

url_and = "https://api.test.com/api/3.0/listings/"

android_token = '68as76df87s86df7asd76f87as6df78sfd'
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Token " + android_token,
    'platform': 'android'
}

data_android = {
    'mailing_details':'3',
    'abcoupay':'false',
    'price':'55.00',
    'description':'Test description',
    'title':'TEST drill machine and others.',
    'meetup':'false',
    'condition':'2',
    'mailing':'true',
    'collection_id':'24'
}

urls = []
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/product_images"):
    if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG")):
        x = os.getcwd()+"\\"+file
        urls.append(x)

files = []
x = 0
for file in urls:
    files.append("'photo_"+str(x)+"': ('image_"+str(x)+".jpg', open('"+file+"', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')")
    x+=1

# files = {
#             'photo_0': ('image_0.jpg', open('E:/products files/Drill machine/1.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
#             'photo_1': ('image_1.jpg', open('E:/products files/Drill machine/2.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg')        
#         }

response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data_android,files=files,headers=headers)
print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

**Error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cookies.py", line 102, in <module>
    response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data_android,files=files,headers=headers)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 504, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 141, in _encode_files
    for (k, v) in files:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: `url_and,data=data_android` are you sure about that comma?

Comment: [files should be passed as a dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). I need to find a better example but it's clear from the error that it's expecting a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `files` parameter for `requests.request` should be a dict where the keys are file names and the values are file content or file objects. You should therefore build your `files` variable as a dict instead:

```
files = {'image_%s.jpg' % x: open(file, 'rb') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
```

If you need the content type as well, you can make the dict values 3-tuples that contain the file name, the file object and the content type:

```
files = {'image_%s.jpg' % x: ('image_%s.jpg' % x, open(file, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
```

Comment: I am facing this error now maybe for the double slash 

```



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cookies.py", line 91, in <module>
    files = {'image_%s.jpg' % x: open(file, 'rb') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
  File "cookies.py", line 91, in <dictcomp>
    files = {'image_%s.jpg' % x: open(file, 'rb') for x, file in enumerate(urls)}
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\PENTEST-POCS\\python\\1.jpg'
```

Comment: So does the file `E:\PENTEST-POCS\python\1.jpg` actually exist?

Comment: Yes it is maybe problem having for the double black slash.

Comment: problem solved.There is problem with extension. I fixed it thank you very much.

Comment: Hi I need content-type : image/jpeg in files do you how can I add this to your code thanks

Comment: Just like this 
`
files = {'photo_%s.jpg' % x: open(file, 'rb') for x, file in enumerate(urls), 'image/jpeg'}
`
I don't know the exact syntax

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly then. By the way can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Comment: Hi I marked it answer as correct but seems little bit array problem like suppose I have 5 urls in my urls array it only taking 4 urls and sending the request. It didn't count the last urls. Do know what can be the reason ?

Thanks Any way

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about why your last file isn't sent though as it shouldn't happen. Perhaps you can ask about it in a new question so that more people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your *files* should be passed as a dict or a list of tuples and you are not doing that. You could do below,

```
files.append(("photo_"+str(x), ("image_"+str(x)+".jpg", open(file, "rb"), "image/jpeg")))
```